# Unhandled Runtime Exception when creating a Client Component in Next JS v13.3.0

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I've got a trivial component in my Next JS website. When I try to make this a Client Component, the page fails to load in the browser and I get the following unhandled runtime exception: `SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON`.

The following is the code for the component which works... however if I uncomment the first line, it all turns to custard :-(

```
// 'use client';

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <div>
            Testing 1, 2, 3!
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm using Next JS 13.3.0 with the experimental appDir turned on...

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}
```

Not sure if that could be related. This particular component is not in the `app` folder though - I moved it out instead to a `components` folder in case there was any funny business going on (I read [here](https://dev.to/zenstack/fun-with-nextjs-13-server-components-o37) that components in the `app` folder are Server Components by default).

I'm stumped at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain next.js supports the `use client` directive? Any examples you have seen?

Comment: Yeah they refer to it explicitly [in their docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#convention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that was solved on the canary release last week (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/47704)

Basically it's an error that only affects Windows developers and a "patch" that seems to work (until v13.3.1 drops) is to use arrow functions for pages/components that have `use client`.

In your example:

```
// 'use client';

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Testing 1, 2, 3!
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Thanks Pau! That workaround works fine.